# Why do I only see SYS and INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables? Access 2007 ODB to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I was finally able to create my ODBC connection but now when I go to External Data > ODBC > LINK TABLES using my ODBC connection in Access 2007 I get a huge list of tables such as

```
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS
```

etc.....

and a whole bunch of

```
sys.all_columns

sys.all_objects

sys.all_parameters
```

etc...

the only tables that i really need are tables such as

```
dbo.users

dbo.stats

dbo.customers
```

etc...

but none of those tables are on the list of table that I am able to choose from to link.

Does anyone know why I can't see or link to the DBO tables I need?

(by the way i created a new user login in order to create my ODBC connection)

Comment: Does the user have select permissions on those tables?

Comment: I'm going to check that now. I just logged in to the account using SSMS and noticed that I did not see any of the tables so it seems to be an issue with the creation of the new account and not an ODBC connection. Thanks for helping me realize that. I will post back with what I find.

Comment: Sounds like no permissions on the `dbo` schema.

Comment: I added the select permissions to the user for the tables i needed and now it works perfectly. It was a permissions issue. THANK YOU both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Jimbo and Shark's comments I was able to fix my problem by adjusting the permission for the tables I wanted to see. I did not have SELECT permission on the tables so I was not able to see them. Once I added the SELECT permission to the tables I was then able to see my data perfectly.